# How to skip a column arrangement spacing for a specific composable?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a `Column` with an arrangement of `Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp)`. This way I don't have to sandwich my composables with `Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(16.dp)` but what if I need to ignore the spacing for a specific area? Is this possible?

--- Composable
--- Spacing (By Arrangement)
--- Composable
--- Spacing (By Arrangement)
--- Composable
--- Composable **<-- Ignore spacing**

--- Spacing (By Arrangement)
--- Composable

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone has the same problem, I solved this by wrapping the components in another column and overriding the arrangement.

```kotlin
Column(
    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
    ...
) {
    Text(...)
    Text(...)
    Column(verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top) {
        Text(...)
        Text(...)
    }
    Text(...)
}
```